# show default image in razor if there is no user image

Tags: asp.net, razor

This statement is not working, i want to show default image if there is no image uploaded pls help

```
  @if (latestrow.thumb == null)
                     {
                         <img src="~/Images/no-pic.gif"/>
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         <img src="@latestrow.thumb"/>
                     }
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Exception? Unexpected result? If the result is unexpected, what is the expected vs actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your code.  Assuming latestrow.thumb is null, you'd receive the no-pic.gif.

My only guess is that latestrow.thumb has some value other than null.  Perhaps using this would be a better approach assuming the value of thumb could be blank or null (and assuming it is a string):

```
@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(latestrow.thumb))
```

If this doesn't work, check the model being sent to the view and see what's in that property.  Chances are it's populated with some value, even perhaps a blank space.

Good luck.

Comment: i am using web pages so no model is there and still doesn't work. Thanks